# PayPal API - Transaction Search API: Response 400 INVALID REQUEST

Tags: python, paypal, python-requests, http-status-code-400

I am trying to get a list of all transactions from my PayPal Business account by using the Transaction Search API, but I keep getting the 400 INVALID_REQUEST response.

According to [this documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/transaction-search/), I am doing everything correctly with the headers.
I also gave access to my app to do this kind of search.  Could anyone help me?

```
import requests, json

USERNAME = <MY USERNAME>
KEY = <MY SECRET KEY>
TOKEN = <MY TOKEN - GENERATED BY POSTMAN>

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json",
           "Accept-Language": "en_US",
           "Authorization": "Bearer <MY TOKEN>",
           "Accept": "application/json"
          }

LINK = "https://api-m.paypal.com"
GET = "/v1/reporting/transactions?start_date=2021-01-01T00:00:00-0700&end_date=2021-06-01T00:00:00-0700"
GET_LINK = LINK + GET

response = requests.get(GET_LINK, auth=(USERNAME, KEY), headers=headers)
print(response)
```

Thanks

Comment: how did you create this code? `POSTMAN` has function to generate code for different languages. Did you generate code with `postman`?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: do you use link to Live/Production environment  with `token` generated by `postman`?

Comment: did you check `print(response.text)`? I recreated all code, run it and get error `400` but in `response.text` I got explanation: `"issue":"Date range is greater than 31 days"` If I change dates then it works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated all code, generated `TOKEN`, ran request and got error `400`

... but in `response.text` I got explanation:

```
"issue":"Date range is greater than 31 days"
```

If I change dates to

```
        'start_date': '2021-01-01T00:00:00-0700',
        'end_date':   '2021-02-01T00:00:00-0700',
```

then it works for me.

**BTW:** You need `(USERNAME, KEY)` only to generate `TOKEN` and later you can use only `TOKEN`.

---

My full code used for tests:

It needs only `CLIENT_ID` and `SECRET` because it runs code to get `TOKEN`

```
import requests

# --- constants ---

CLIENT_ID = "ARg..."  # 80 chars
SECRET    = "EAl..."  # 80 chars

#ENDPOINT = "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com"  # Sandbox - doesn't have access to transactions
ENDPOINT = "https://api-m.paypal.com"          # Live

DEBUG = True

# --- functions ---

def display_response(response):
    print('response:', response)
    print('url:', response.url)
    print('text:', response.text)    

def display_data(data):
    for key, value in data.items():
        if key == 'scope':
            for item in value.split(' '):
                print(key, '=', item)
        else:
            print(key, '=', value)
    
def get_token():
    if DEBUG:
        print('--- get token ---')
    
    url = ENDPOINT + '/v1/oauth2/token'
    
    headers = {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Accept-Language": "en_US",
    }
        
    payload = {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials"
    }
        
    response = requests.post(url, auth=(CLIENT_ID, SECRET), data=payload)

    if DEBUG:
        display_response(response)    
    
    data = response.json()
    
    if DEBUG:
        display_data(data)
    
    return data['access_token']

def get_transactions():
    if DEBUG:
        print('--- transaction ---')
    
    url = ENDPOINT + "/v1/reporting/transactions"
    
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept-Language": "en_US",
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {TOKEN}",
        "Accept": "application/json"
    }
    
    payload = {
        'start_date': '2021-01-01T00:00:00-0700',
        'end_date':   '2021-02-01T00:00:00-0700',
    }    
    
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload)

    if DEBUG:
        display_response(response)    
    
    data = response.json()

    if DEBUG:
        display_data(data)
        
# --- main ---

TOKEN = get_token()

print('--- token ---')
print('TOKEN:', TOKEN)

get_transactions()
```